# Transfer each details in one pop up table on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button (add to bag) to transfer detail of product in the pop up table.

However, this far the code I have is only able to transfer one detail of product to the pop up table.

Since I have many list of products, I have to transfer this detail of product in one pop up table.

How to make this pop up table is filled with information based on the product which is clicked by customer?

**This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/whjc0tta/1/**

This is the html code that show the list of product (in this example I will only show two list of products)

```
        <ul id="yourlist" style="display:inline-block; overflow:hidden;">
        <li>
            <img src="indonu-image/hitam.jpg"/>
            <p class="content-p"><span class="product-name">Forbiden Rice</span></br>
                <span class="content-pp"><span class="content-info">Good Rice</span></br><span class="price-info">200.000</span>
                </span></p>

           <div class="spanish">               
                <span>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                   onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
                            document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Add to bag</a></span>                    

                <span>Buy</span>

           </div>
        </li>


        <li>
            <img src="indonu-image/hitam.jpg"/>
            <p class="content-p"><span class="product-name">Not Forbiden Rice</span></br>
                <span class="content-pp">Good Rice</br>200.000
                </span></p>

           <div class="spanish">               
                <span>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                   onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
                            document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Add to bag</a></span>                    

                <span>Buy</span>

           </div>
       </li>
    </ul>


    <!--Pop Up Div-->       
    <div id="light" class="white_content">

    <div id="headerLightBox">
            Berikut kami tampilkan bon belanja Anda hari ini. Pastikan seluruh spesifikasi sesuai dengan
            kebutuhan Anda.
    </div>

    <table id="tableInformation" cellspacing="0">
    <tr id="headerTableInformation">
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="contentTableInformation">
        <td id="productName-content"></td>
        <td id="description-content"></td>
        <td id="priceContent"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="buttonWrapper">

    <p id="processBlocked">
        <a href = "javascript:void(0)" 
           onclick ="document.getElementById('secondLight').style.display='block';
                     document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
                     document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Processed</a></p>

    <p id="closeBlocked">
        <a href = "javascript:void(0)" 
           onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
                     document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Cancel</a></p>

        <p id="expired">Pesanan Anda akan expired pada tanggal: </p>

    </div>

</div>
```

And here is the javascript that trasnfer the details of one product to the pop up table:

```
$('#productName-content').html($('.product-name').val());   
$('#productName-content').html($('.product-name').html()); 

$('#description-content').html($('.content-info').val());   
    $('#description-content').html($('.content-info').html()); 

$('#priceContent').html('Rp. ' + $('.price-info').html());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got a number of things to address, but foremost, your jQuery is not bound to your "add to bag" buttons. So what is happening is that, before you even click any buttons, jQuery has already copied the first product's details into your lightbox view. And then clicking the "add to bag" button isn't actually doing anything other than showing the lightbox with the pre-populated details.

So you need to put your jQuery code which does the actual copying of product details into a click event that is bound to the "add to bag" buttons. Then, you should also remove all the inline javascript which is showing/hiding your lightbox and also move that into your jQuery section. Third, your product information HTML is not consistent -- make sure each product has the same classed spans wrapped around each type of detail, otherwise jQuery won't be able to grab it. Here's some cleaned up HTML:

```
<ul id="yourlist" style="display:inline-block; overflow:hidden;">
    <li>
        <img src="indonu-image/hitam.jpg" />
        <p class="content-p"><span class="product-name">Forbiden Rice</span>

            </br>   <span class="content-pp"><span class="content-info">Product One</span>

            </br><span class="price-info">200.000</span>
</span>
        </p>
        <div class="spanish">   <span>
                    <a href="#">Add to bag</a></span>   <span>Buy</span>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="indonu-image/hitam.jpg" />
        <p class="content-p"><span class="product-name">Not Forbiden Rice</span>

            </br>   <span class="content-pp"><span class="content-info">Product Two</span></span>
            </br><span class="price-info">200.000
                    </span>

        </p>
        <div class="spanish">   <span>
                    <a href="#">Add to bag</a></span>   <span>Buy</span>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<!--Pop Up Div-->
<div id="light" class="white_content">
    <div id="headerLightBox">Berikut kami tampilkan bon belanja Anda hari ini. Pastikan seluruh spesifikasi sesuai dengan kebutuhan Anda.</div>
    <table id="tableInformation" cellspacing="0">
        <tr id="headerTableInformation">
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="contentTableInformation">
            <td id="productName-content"></td>
            <td id="description-content"></td>
            <td id="priceContent"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="buttonWrapper">
        <p id="processBlocked"> <a href="#">Processed</a>

        </p>
        <p id="closeBlocked"> <a href="#">Cancel</a>

        </p>
        <p id="expired">Pesanan Anda akan expired pada tanggal:</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(".spanish").on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    // get the product details container
    var $product_container = $(this).closest('.spanish').prev('.content-p');
    var $product_name = $product_container.find('.product-name').text();
    var $product_info = $product_container.find('.content-info').text();
    var $product_price = $product_container.find('.price-info').text();

    $('#productName-content').text($product_name);
    $('#description-content').text($product_info);
    $('#priceContent').text($product_price);

    $('#fade').fadeOut();
    $('#light').fadeIn();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('#processBlocked a').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#secondLight').fadeIn();
    $('#light').fadeOut();
    $('#fade').fadeIn();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('#closeBlocked a').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#light').fadeOut();
    $('#fade').fadeIn();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whjc0tta/6/

Comment: Excellent answer with excellent solution. And also, this must be an excellent reading for me to improve my javascript studying. thank you very much.